# Can my family get a tourist visa for Switzerland from India

Tags: visas, schengen, indian-citizens, visa-refusals, switzerland

My husband is working in Switzerland on an L permit. We are Indian.

Can my sister get tourist visa to visit for 1 month? She is not married and not working at present.

Will there be a possibility of refusal when she applies for a visa ?

Comment: If your sister has indian citizenship she can certainly apply for a Swiss visa in India. I don't understand what's the relevance of your husband's work permit ?

Comment: Will she get tourist visa

Comment: @blackbird Is that the L permit is limited to a short term, a year or less?

Comment: Because she's not working and not married

Comment: No one here can assure you of that, if she supplies all the documents they ask her she has a good chance of getting it

Comment: @Dorothy it's a [short term residence permit](https://www.ch.ch/en/renewal-overview-swiss-residence-permit/)

Comment: @blackbird yes, but I wonder whether that's part of her concern.

Comment: If she resides in India, she can and should apply in India (and nowhere else). It's difficult to predict the outcome but being unmarried and not working does probably increase the likelihood of a negative decision. I don't think your and your husband's status make all that much of difference.

Comment: Indeed, one month seems like a long time.

Answer (score 4):

> Can my sister get tourist visa to visit for 1 month?

She is entitled to apply for a Schengen just like anybody else who holds an Indian passport.

From the Directorate-General for Migration and Home Affairs tables we can see that Switzerland is the 9th largest issuer of Schengens, having issued 429,399 multiple-entry visas in 2013.  Their refusal rate is 6.1%.

From the same data we can see that Indian nationals were issued 659,039 multiple-entry Schengens in 2013 and that Indian nationals constitute *the 7th largest end-user of Schengens world-wide*. The overall refusal rate for Indian nationals is 6.5%.  The site archives here may looked skewed because we only get the refusals.

So statistics give no reason to believe that India is excluded from the Schengen programme or is disadvantaged in some way.

> Will there be a possibility of refusal when she applies for a visa ?

Absolutely yes, there is a real possibility, but no one can predict the outcome of a particular individual's application.  Realistic predictions are possible only when you spread all the individual's evidence out and examine it as a whole.  If you think your sister's circumstances are weak, then advise her to apply when things are improved.

> She is not married and not working at present.

These things will elevate her risk, especially if she is of marriageable age coming from South Asia.  There's little to be done about that, it's just part of *WHAT IS*.  She needs to have a strong application in order to be successful and the biggest part of that will be her premise. You didn't tell us her premise so the 'best practices' advice is to be really sure the premise is strong and well-supported.

Note:

Statistics pulled from [Visa Statistics for Consulates 2013](http://ec.europa.eu/dgs/home-affairs/what-we-do/policies/borders-and-visas/visa-policy/docs/synthese_2013_with_filters_en.xls) (which will download as a spreadsheet and can be rolled up).

Comment: (+1) You can find more recent stats on the website from the [DG Migration and Home Affairs](http://ec.europa.eu/dgs/home-affairs/what-we-do/policies/borders-and-visas/visa-policy/index_en.htm) (although not per nationality but only per consulate/implicitly by country of residence). Instead of the cover of your course's notes, which really isn't useful, could you provide a proper reference to this report (a link is not needed if you don't have one but a picture is not a way to cite a document)?

Comment: @Relaxed I would love to do better, I will try to find an exact link.  Yes I agree that my selection of images is not the strongest. I must try to give a wonderful answer!

Comment: Don't worry about images and links, if you have the think before you or a proper citation, provide that (it would include a title and a date at least).

Comment: @Relaxed can you check it now?